# what does ls / > mean?

Tags: command-line

I found

```
ls / > output.txt
```

creates `output.txt` which contains names of folders inside rootfs.
But I can't understand what does `ls / >` exactly mean.
I know command `ls` is used to list all files in the location but what does `ls / >` do?
I did `man ls` to read definition of `ls / >` but I couldn't find that there.

Comment: @user535733 ok so ls / prints out files inside root linux folder and the outputs will be redirected to output.txt . is it right?

Comment: Beside the point, but for "roofts", you mean "rootfs", right? But actually, you mean "the root of the filesystem", right? cause rootfs gets mounted over during startup (IIRC)

Comment: @wjandrea yes, a typo sorry

Comment: Related: [What's is the difference between ">" and ">>" in shell command?](/q/382793/301745)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/` is the root directory, which contains directories like `home` and `root` as well as files like `swapfile` if you have it set up.

`>` sends ([redirects](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)) the output of a command to a file, in this case, `output.txt`.

So `ls / > output.txt` means "list the contents of the root directory and send the output to `output.txt`."